# change read only permissions of Ubuntu internal drive as external drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, read-only

I have an old laptop with ubuntu and somehow It got crashed and I got the internal hard drive out of it to use as external drive. Here comes the hiccup, the drive is read-only and I can't change the ownership. I have tried `chmod` and `chown` already.

`chown` outputs `input/output error`!

[image: pic]

Comment: If you can read you can copy the data from it. Why not do that and work on the data from your own system?

Comment: I/O errors often indicate a problem with the storage device. I recommend that  you check the drive as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10